# Dart syntax highlighting is not working in vs code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

i have been using vs code for flutter for 3 months and now i got into this issue
syntax prediction works and flutter run is also working but syntax color is gone

Also i have uninstalled every extensions and reinstalled vs code
here is the console screenshot

[image]

Comment: did you try to set your theme again?

Comment: Check the solution in comments :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63229817/vscode-not-able-to-recognize-the-code-flutter-dart

Answer (score 0):

It appears that one of the files in the Dart extension may be corrupt on your disk (syntaxs/dart.json). I would try to uninstall the extension and re-install it.

If that does not help, please check the contents of the .vscode-extensions folder in your home directory in the Dart-Code folder syntaxes/dart.json and see why it is not valid json.

I've seen this once before (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/73134) though it's not clear why it happened.